# problem with installing a repository on remote server with CentOS 7 without root permission

Tags: centos, sudo, root

I am trying to install [Chipyard](https://chipyard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Chipyard-Basics/Initial-Repo-Setup.html) Toolchain on a remote system with cshrc. I am connecting to it via ssh.

All the required dependencies were already installed on the system. I checked them with `rpm -q` command. So I skipped installing them.

I've done the setup phase as well (i.e. ./scripts/init-submodules-no-riscv-tools.sh was successful-- generated the expected output on env.sh file)

My problem is with the buiding the toolchains where I'm getting the errors:

[image]

I also recorded the full build process and its [here](https://filetransfer.io/data-package/tSVhrbfm#link).

My question is do i need to install the dependecies again (or upadate them) to get rid of the errors? if so could you please guide me how becaues I'm not the sudo.

I asked the admin but they replied that the admin is only for advanced stuff.

I'm not very experinced with linux. Any guidance will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

```
Installing toolchain to /local/data0/AS/chipyard/riscv-tools-install
=>  Starting riscv-gnu-toolchain build
==>  Initializing riscv-gnu-toolchain submodule
==>  Removing existing riscv-gnu-toolchain/build directory
==>  Configuring riscv-gnu-toolchain
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... (cached) /bin/grep
checking for bash... /bin/sh
checking for __gmpz_init in -lgmp... yes
checking for mpfr_init in -lmpfr... yes
checking for mpc_init2 in -lmpc... yes
checking for curl... /bin/curl
checking for wget... /bin/wget
checking for ftp... /bin/ftp
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating scripts/wrapper/awk/awk
config.status: creating scripts/wrapper/sed/sed
==>  Building riscv-gnu-toolchain
mkdir -p /local/data0/AS/chipyard/riscv-tools-install/.test || \
    (echo "Sorry, you don't have permission to write to" \
     "'/local/data0/AS/chipyard/riscv-tools-install', use --prefix to specify" \
     "another path, or use 'sudo make' if you *REALLY* want to" \
     "install into '/local/data0/AS/chipyard/riscv-tools-install'" && exit 1)
rm -rf stamps/build-gdb-newlib build-gdb-newlib
mkdir build-gdb-newlib
rm -r /local/data0/AS/chipyard/riscv-tools-install/.test
cd build-gdb-newlib && CC_FOR_TARGET=riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc /local/data0/AS/chipyard/toolchains/riscv-tools/riscv-gnu-toolchain/build/../riscv-gdb/configure \
    --target=riscv64-unknown-elf \
     \
    --prefix=/local/data0/AS/chipyard/riscv-tools-install \
     \
    --disable-werror \
    --with-expat=yes  \
    --enable-gdb \
    --disable-gas \
    --disable-binutils \
    --disable-ld \
    --disable-gold \
    --disable-gprof
mkdir -p stamps/ && touch stamps/check-write-permission
```

I ran the ./configure command in 'chipyard/toolchains/riscv-tools/riscv-gnu-toolchain. I passed both current path and the path 'local/data0/AS/chipyard/riscv-tools-install' and build the toolchains for each, but still getting the same permission error. could you tell me where I'm doing wrong please?

-Although there some error messages in the generated config.log file : configure:2185: gcc -V >&5 gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V' gcc: fatal error: no input files I dont know if that matters, though

Comment: looks like the file "py-value.c" has something unreferenced in line 1000. Since you had to copy a picture instead of just copying the text (as it is usual, especially with linux terminals) some of the crucial info of that line has been omitted.... Remove your picture and paste the output of the terminal (the first 10 lines should be enough) into your question....

Comment: I added the whole output in my post. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm not downloading the whole stuff. Copy the first 10 lines as I asked you to as **text** and **not** as an image and paste them into your question.

Answer (score 0):

> mkdir -p /local/data0/AS/chipyard/riscv-tools-install/.test || 
> (echo "Sorry, you don't have permission to write to" 
> "'/local/data0/AS/chipyard/riscv-tools-install', use --prefix to specify" 
> "another path, or use 'sudo make' if you *REALLY* want to" 
> "install into '/local/data0/AS/chipyard/riscv-tools-install'" && exit 1)

You are not allowed to write to /local.... It even gives you a tip how to circumvent it (by using `sudo make` or using the `--prefix` flag)

But I do not think that the /local directory exists... which leads to the same message. So you could use the key "--prefix" which takes an existing path as an argument:

```
./configure --prefix /path/to/the/location/that/exists..
```

You might consider to get acquainted with "make" before building code ..

Comment: It’s probably `./configure --prefix=/whatever` and not `make --prefix`, which would just generate an error.

Comment: @jsbillings I just tried this but it shows "./configure: command not found"

Comment: Also there is no configure file in chipyard/ or chipyard/scripts. There is one in chipyard/generators/riscv-sodor for example but ./configure is not there as wll. How can I overcome this? Is there way to do this if I'm not the 'sudo' ?

Comment: It looks like the `build-toolchain.sh` script takes a --prefix argument that it’ll pass on to the build process. The output clearly shows autoconf so I’m sure a configure script is being generated and run with the prefix passed along.